# L7805 frying when no load is connected

Tags: voltage-regulator

I was using an L7805 voltage regulator from 12V to 5V to power an Atmega328P and connected circuits. I have worked quite a lot on that circuit and indeed some accidental shorts happened in the way. Now the circuit seemed mature but it behaved unstable. So I removed the L7805 to test it: I connected the L7805 IN pin directly to 12V power supply and the GND pin to power supply GND. I left the OUT pin not connected and didn't use the capacitors. When I powered the 12V I heard it frying so I detached the power immediately.

Is this a sign the L7805 is destroyed or was there something wrong in how I connected it? In my understanding when only the IN and GND pins are connected, the OUT pin should be at 5V and no big current should pass through the IN-GND line.

SOLVED: I can confirm I fried and destroyed it by accidentally reverse polarizing it. I can tell this because I did that also to another L7805, and I fried that one too. Yes, I know.

Comment: You need to use input and output capacitors to prevent oscillations within the regulator. Such oscillations may cause heavy power dissipation.

Comment: You need the input capacitor if you use long leads and you need a minimum load of 5 mA to be in spec for regulation.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I now tested with two capacitors mounted as in test circuit from the datasheet) and a 440 Ohm load. L7805 (with heatsink) heats up very high in a few seconds. The 12V power supply pushes it's fan very strongly, meaning the test circuit is drawing a lot of current. However this does not happen when I power directly the 440 Ohm load with the 12V.

Comment: @Arsenal My reply to MathKeepsMeBusy is the same to you. Please check it up here. Thanks

Comment: It should not be damaged by no caps and no load. I've used a lot of them and never seen anything like that happen. Unless the PSU is outputting pulsed DC, like a phone charger might, then you've just got a knackered 7805.

Comment: @TonyM The PSU should be fine, it's a general purpose DC 30A PSU. But as I said I made some accidental shorts on the original circuit so it's possible I damaged it, although I don't get what kind of situation would damage it. Maybe applying 12V to the output pin or maybe too much heat when soldering(I'm not too expert). I ordered a few more because I too think it's damaged. I'll compare the difference.

Answer (score 6):

There is **no** way to damage it by connecting just input and ground properly with no external components unless the input voltage is reversed or it exceeds the absolute maximum input voltage.

Unlike many newer (which have various other advantages) parts L7805 are very stable and reliable parts and you have to try exceptionally hard to get them to fail or even oscillate.

Take care if you use the complementary 7905 parts as the pinout is different (tab and middle pin is still the most negative voltage, but now that's the input, and the 'left' pin is GND rather than input).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found today I have been able to destroy TWO L7805. I am not sure how I did with the first one, but with the second one I surely reversed the voltage(I put 12 V on output pin). It burns instantly. There was a misunderstanding in wire colors and voltage was reversed. Now I have another L7805 and it works fine. The L7805 frying while connected with no load was frying because it was already destroyed.

Comment: @GianfDS Yes, generally damaged semiconductors like to become a short, unless you physically destroy the connections (blow it apart or blow the bonding wires off).